# I have English words in Kurdish pages

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, multi-language, language

Good Day,
I have a wordpress draft website with woocommerce plugin (https://landroveriraq.com/toto), I build this website with (3) languages (English, Arabic, Kurdish) the English is a default language.
I have no problem in all website except in Kurdish version has an English word instead of Kurdish like this page (https://landroveriraq.com/toto/ku/product/cw166b-3/) you will find (Description, Reviews, Related products, Email, Name, etc...).

I need your help to guide me how to fix this words and insert a Kurdish words instead of this.

Thanks a lot,
Omar

Comment: I'd guess these are generated by WooCommerce and the translations are missing - on [translate.wordpress.com](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/) there's a fair number of translations missing for Kurdish. You'll probably have to create your own translations and update the .po or .mo file you have for WooCommerce, but I don't know how to do that: maybe you can download them from translate.wordpress.com if you can contribute them there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I have no problem with translation but with how to insert this translated words instead of English .. Yesterday I tried to edit the .po file but honestlyI don't know which one should I edit because there are a lot of files with .po.